# Windows boot and system partition on different disks

Tags: windows, system-reserved-partition

I have a problem which was caused probably by years of patch repairing my system multiple times and that resulted in having a windows (C:) drive that acts as the boot drive and recently converted to gpt (I want to test win11 as I tested every new OS) and beside a lot of other drives another drive that contains system files. Not only that, but the other drive have 3 system reserved partitions beside the data partition!
I either want to get all the relevant files and partitions on the boot SSD or be able to recognize which system reserved partition can I delete from the old drive to be able to convert that one to GPT aswell (with 4 partitions I'm unable to convert or for other reason I dont get the option).
I have used the EASEUS Partition Master tool to convert mbr to gpt because for some reason the built in mbr2gpt did not work.
I also checked all 3 of the reserved partitions to maybe get any idea which one was not used in a while but all were used (Access time is constant).
I attach a picture from disk management.

[image: disk management]

Comment: You need UEFI, Secure Boot on the same main disk and TPM to run Windows 11. At this point, your system does not look like it will run Windows 11. (I do have Window 11 pre-release running).

Comment: I have all of these, TPM from CPU, DISK1 on GPT but since the system wont boot without my Disk2  connected (some system reserved partition issue I guess?) and I cant convert that disk to GPT.

Comment: You will need to setup the computer again with UEFI on the main C: disk.